# Android Instant App Failure to parse App

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I'm trying to run my instant app module but I've got the error **DevMan error: Failed to parse app: /data/local/tmp/aia/...**. What leads this error, any idea?

However, when I tried to run the command **adb install -r -t my-base-debug.apk** it gives success.

Can anyone please help me to figure out?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you post the full log?

Comment: @AdamK This is all I have :
06/02 16:48:22: Launching instantapp-myapp
Uploading Instant App to pre O device.
Starting / refreshing Instant App services
DevMan error: Failed to parse app: /data/local/tmp/aia/instantapp-myapp-debug.zip 
$ adb shell pm uninstall com.my.app.insantapp
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
Error while Uploading and registering Instant App

Comment: Can you check "adb logcat" as well, it should have the reason for why the uploading/registering Instant App bit failed.

Comment: @AdamK Hey thanks for your reply and suggestion. I got something from it, try to solve it. I get back if I won't. Thanks again

Comment: While trying to launch instant app below Android O I am getting this DevMan error: Unable to connect to Google Play Service. ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}  
$ adb shell pm uninstall com.speedoji.android.internet.speed.meter.test.master.wifi.booster
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
Error while Uploading and registering Instant App

Comment: @PinkeshDarji see this post for that issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44052798/268156

Comment: @AdamK can we get an id from url to the instant app page? For example, my feature will be product detail page, and when user clicked the product, it should pass product id to my feature app. Any idea?

Comment: @PinkeshDarji if you have new questions then create a new post. for that question, this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44080377/268156

Comment: @AdamK Sure I will do that

Comment: @AdamK whenever I click the link and verify button in complete the association part, it gives : 
- Adding asset statements failed
- Failed to link strings to AndroidManifest file
- Failed to add autoVerify to intent-filter elements
-Success!...

Why these 3 of them failed? And is it an obstacle for uploading apk to play store? Thanks

Comment: @MichealDanne yes having correct intent-filters are needed for Instant Apps. I see you already posted up another question about this so hopefully an answer can be posted to help you there.

Comment: Hey, one more question. How to produce APK? I'm trying to produce from command line, and upload them to Play Store, it says " sorry we could not save your changes." Then, I try to generate signed APK tool from android studio, then upload it to Play Store, it says "Your Feature APKs containes "productdetail" either does not exist or was not included". What am I doing wrong? @AdamK

Comment: are you trying to upload single apks one by one? you need to zip them all up together and upload that one zip file.

Comment: @senaaltun i hope you problem has been resolve now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Preview 3.0 - Application installation failed when running instant app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44051850/android-studio-preview-3-0-application-installation-failed-when-running-instan)

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar issue when using the demo project to develop the InstantApp.
After check the logcat, say some issue related to the "version code", 
then add the `versionCode YourProjectVersionCodeHere` and `versionName YourProjectVersionNameHere` in the base feature `build.gradle` file (in the `android {}`), the instant app change run on my emulator(API 25).